# Apache HTTP client source not found in Android 15

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have downloaded the source folder of Android 15 from the SDK manager.

But I don't get the source code of Apache HTTP client in the folder which is bundled by the Android distribution. I can see the code of other components like java ,json ,Android etc.

Am I missing anything or anyone aware of the problem?